# Send message with Twilio and Delphi

Tags: delphi, twilio

I've tried to send message with Twilio

But I got authentication error :

```
{"code":20003,"message":"Authentication Error - No credentials provided","more_info":"https:\/\/www.twilio.com\/docs\/errors\/20003","status":401}
```

The `Account SID` and `Auth Token` changed as required
The Code:

```
    // Create environment variables (named below) with your Twilio credentials
client := TTwilioClient.Create(
  GetEnvironmentVariable('*************************a271d22b1'),
  GetEnvironmentVariable('*************************3647817'));
// Your Twilio phone number
fromPhoneNumber := '+12*******40';
// Your destination number (for trials, this needs to be your mobile #)
toPhoneNumber := '+**********20';
// Make a phone call
Writeln('----- Phone Call -----');

allParams := TStringList.Create;
allParams.Add('From=' + fromPhoneNumber);
allParams.Add('To=' + toPhoneNumber);
allParams.Add('Url=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml');
// POST to the Calls resource
response := client.Post('Calls', allParams);
if response.Success then
  Writeln('Call SID: ' + response.ResponseData.GetValue<string>('sid'))
else if response.ResponseData <> nil then
  Writeln(response.ResponseData.ToString)
else
  Writeln('HTTP status: ' + response.HTTPResponse.StatusCode.ToString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetEnvironmentVariable` retrieves a value when you pass in the key.

Let's say you have a key/value pair, `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=1234356789`. To access the value, you will need to pass in the key: `GetEnvironmentVariable('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')`.

In your code snippet, you are passing in the value itself (i.e. `*************************a271d22b1`)

You should set the environment variables first.

As a quick workaround, you can just pass in:

```
client := TTwilioClient.Create(
  '*************************a271d22b1',
  '*************************3647817');
```

But you'll definitely want to hide your credentials.